# I'm trying to convert an existing makefile for macOS to one that will run under mingw-W64 on Windows10

Tags: makefile, windows-10, gfortran

This is the makefile for MacOS The source directory contains the source files plus the makefile and srclist.make file

```
# makefile for molex on macOS

OBJDIR = ../Objects
SRCDIR = ./Source

include srclist.make

    FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -x f77-cpp-input -ffixed-line-length-132 -fno-align-commons -I$(SRCDIR) -O3

OBJECTS  = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SRCLIST)) ))

SOURCES = $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/, $(SRCLIST) )

vpath %.f $(SRCDIR)
vpath %.inc $(SRCDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.f
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

molex : $(OBJECTS)
    $(FC) -o molex $^

.PHONY : clean


clean:
    rm $(OBJDIR)/*.o
```

srclist.make contains a list of fortran and include files to converted to object code which are placed in a separate Objects folder

```
  SRCLIST = \
      molex.f  \
      background.f  \
      bnu.f \
      charfns.f \
      checkparam.f \
      escape.f \
      extrap.f \
      fcn.f \
      fdjac.f \
      fmin.f \
      funcv.f \
      getfs.f \
      idtrans.f \
      initcoll.f \
      initx.f \
      intensity.f \
      levpop.f  \
      lnsrch2.f \
      loadmol.f \
      lubksb.f \
      ludcmp2.f \
      newt3.f \
      nextline.f \
      output.f \
      tau.f \
      taudust.f \
      Tex.f \
      bug.inc \
      collisions.inc \
      constants.inc \
      control.inc \
      moldata.inc \
      nlevmax.inc \
      nmax.inc \
      parameters.inc \
      radiative.inc \
```

I've tried placing escape backslashes in the macOS makefile and ran in cmd prmpt with mingw32-make
the environmental Path is set as C:\msys2\mingw-w64\bin

the partly edited makefile follows

```
    # makefile for molex on macOS

OBJDIR = ..\\Objects
SRCDIR = .\\Source

include  srclist.make

    FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -x f77-cpp-input -ffixed-line-length-132 -fno-align-commons -I$(SRCDIR) -O3

#OBJECTS  = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SRCLIST)) ))
OBJECTS  = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)\\, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SRCLIST)) ))

SOURCES = $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/, $(SRCLIST) )

vpath %.f $(SRCDIR)
vpath %.inc $(SRCDIR)

$(OBJDIR)\%.o : %.f
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

molex : $(OBJECTS)
    $(FC) -o molex $^

.PHONY : clean



clean:
    del $(OBJDIR)/*.o
```

The cmd prompt output follows

```
     D:\test_molex_ian\Source>mingw32-make -f makefile molex
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target '..\\Objects\\molex.o', needed by 'molex'.  Stop.
```

I would appreciate some guidance please

Comment: You should always use forward-slashes in pathnames, even on Windows.